# How to search for large directory containing thousands of files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, find, performance

Under the folder

```
/grid/sdh/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfs/appcache
```

we have more than 100 recursive folders.

One of the folders contain thousands of files.
Is it possible to identify this folder?

I am asking because this one folder that contains the thousands of files
and we may have a problem that we can't remove the files there because of the thousands of files.

Comment: could be thousand  or more , in this folder for example if you type ls , then it not return the output because the huge files

Comment: Have you run `fsck` just to make sure that your filesystem is not corrupted?

Comment: no we not run , but why you think about this direction ?

Comment: Because if `ls` fails in the directory, one possible cause is a corrupted filesystem.  `fsck` checks for filesystem corruption.

Comment: With some file systems, the size of the directory files can give an indication of how many entries they have without having to list their content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of items in a directory may be counted using

```
set -- *
```

This sets the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, etc.) to the names in the current directory.
The number of names that `*` expands to is found in `$#`.  If you use the `bash` shell and set the `dotglob` shell option, this will additionally count hidden names.

Using this to find directories under `/grid/sdh/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfs/appcache` that contain more than 1000 names:

```
find /grid/sdh/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfs/appcache \
    -type d -exec bash -O dotglob -c '
        for pathname do
            set -- "$pathname"/*
            if [ "$#" -gt 1000 ]; then
                printf "%d\t%s\n" "$#" "$pathname"
            fi
        done' bash {} +
```

This expands the `*` shell glob in each found directory and outputs the pathname of the directory if there are more than 1000 names in it, along with the number of names.  It does this by executing a short `bash` script for batches of directories.  The script will loop over each batch of directories and for each, it will expand the `*` glob inside it to count the number of entries.  An `if` statement then triggers `printf` if appropriate.

Note that if a directory contains *millions* of names, then it may take  a bit of time to actually expand the `*` glob in that directory.

Comment: do we need to run "set -- *" before we run your find code?

Comment: @yael No, that is not necessary.  That was just a bit of explaining the way that the embedded `bash` script works that `find` calls.

Comment: so when you say "names" it include folders and files - am I correct ? ( I mean also if we have more the 1000 folders under folder , it will print it

Comment: @yael Yes, it would include the names of any entry in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

On a GNU system

```
(export LC_ALL=C
  find /grid/sdh/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfs/appcache -print0 |
    tr '\n\0' '\0\n' |
    sed 's|/[^/]*$||' |
    sort |
    uniq -c |
    sort -rn |
    head |
    tr '\z' '\n')
```

Would list the 10 directories with the most entries.

If the directories have so many files than even listing them would be too expensive, you can try and guess which they are without entering them by looking at their size.

```
 find /grid/sdh/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfs/appcache -type d \
   -size +10000000c -print -prune
```

Would list the directories that are more than 10MB large and not enter them.